# Should I edit a post to replace its image with actual code?

Tags: discussion, edits

Some people likes asking questions with screenshots of their code. But those questions are of poor quality because SO search engine and google can't reference this code.

I'm wondering if it's a good practice to edit those questions by replacing the image with the actual code.

Comment: In theory yes, but it's really something the OP should do. If he can't be bothered, the question deserves a downvote

Comment: Downvote, vote to close and leave a comment telling them to stop being lazy.  You can edit it in by hand if you want, but you'll burn out quickly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it's a good practice to edit those questions by
>   replacing the image with the actual code.

**Yes,** it definitely is a good practice to do so. However, the general norm or practise followed is commenting underneath the question, hinting the OP to add a code block(s) instead of the screenshot.

This'd help them understand the practice and avoid making the same mistake again.